# Calculate Sum of Values of Last 12 months Group by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have requriement where i need to calculate sum of values for each Unique ID for Last 12 Month/365 Days. I also want to create a seperate pandas dataframe for those calculated sum and grouped columns.
For Example:
data

| ID | date | Order_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X8DE9C1382D02F287B6 | 2021-04-23 | 16 |
| X8DE9C1382D02F212N1 | 2021-04-24 | 11 |
| X8DE9C1382D02F222E1 | 2021-04-24 | 9 |
| X8DE9C1312D02F222W1 | 2021-05-24 | 8 |

I tried doing rolling calc window but that is not what i want. Help would be appreaciated.

Comment: use groupby and aggregate

Comment: It seems that you forget the *Pandas* tag?

Comment: roll_calc = data.groupby("id").rolling('365D', on="date")["order_count"].sum(), data = data.set_index(["id", "date"])
data["order_count_12months"] = roll_calc but this gives me undesired results as I just want the sum of order counts for each id over last 12 months

Comment: df[df["date"] >  pd.Timestamp.today() - pd.Timedelta('365D')].groupby(["id"])["Order_Count"].sum()